# How to decode compressed api response?

Tags: c#, api, http, gzip, pcap

I wrote a capture program, it listens to HTTP traffic on network. When I get the API response I can not resolve this because it is compressed by `gzip`. I use `pcapdotnet` for capturing and you can see my sample compressed response following. How can i decode this packet ?

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Encoding: gzip
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Server: Kestrel
BodyType: System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ZB.DTO.FRM.Frame.dSikcaSorulanSorular]
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Fri, 29 Mar 2019 09:51:04 GMT


a
�
```

And you can see compressed body byte array form;

```
{97, 13, 10, 31, 139, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 13, 10}
```

Comment: You need to use a GZipStream to decompress it:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.gzipstream?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: That is byte array not a file and that byte array would contains json object but array length is too short. Is there any hiding or losing option for packet body part

Comment: Use a `MemoryStream` to wrap the byte array with a stream and wrap that stream with a `GZipStream`

Comment: I use pcapdotnet for capturing. Packet not resolve healthy, it return too short data when content type set to gzip, your options right but my problem is not at convert part i have got unknown problem at capturing time.

Comment: Can you post sample code which you are using to capture HTTP responses ?

Comment: Maybe that is because of `Transfer-Encoding: chunked`. You need to merge together more than one `HTTP` message:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding

Comment: What is type of chunked ? You said that i need capture more than one response really ?

Comment: I use following layers from pcap.net                                                                ILayer baseLayer = packet.Ethernet.IpV4.Tcp.Http.ExtractLayer();      HttpResponseLayer httpResponse = (HttpResponseLayer)packet.Ethernet.IpV4.Tcp.Http.ExtractLayer();                         Body part of http response and 97 is length of character set, 13 and 10 is new line and space characters, 31 and 39 are gzip header flags others too, gzip part looks like empty but my api returns many data.